# Can a DataTable be used to update the DB?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

If I bind a `DataViewGrid` to a `DataTable`, and change the data in the grid,

1. How does the `DataTable` get notified of these changes?
2. Does the `DataTable` automatically update the DB?
3. If not, and I have to do it manually, how do I find out what the changes are?
4. Does it make a difference if the `DataTable` was populated from a `DataReader` or something else?

Or the "big picture" question:
Am I doing this all wrong?
I have a database with one table, and I need to display this table and allow editing it. I don't have any fancy designers since this is a custom (not by me) database type and they only provide `DataProvider` (is that what it is called?) classes like `DataReader`, `DataAdapter`, `DataSet`, `DataTable`, etc., but no design-time support. I am also glad for an opportunity to learn how to do all this in code and not with code-generators, but am getting very confused. Until now I always draged-and-dropped all my data needs, not even knowing if I was using readers or sets or whatever.

Thanks a lot.

BTW, are `DataTable`s disconnected, that is in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the DataAdapter and specify the Delete, Insert and Update commands.
This is a decent explanation.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d402f6f4-52c6-48e3-88a6-4d6fbececf8a/

Answer (score 0):

2 - No DataTable is disconnected, so you will need to get the changes back to the Database.

3 - DataTable.GetChanges()